# How to query sql in MS Access 2007 Find Min & Max with DateTime?

Tags: sql, ms-access, datetime, ms-access-2007

i query sql in MS Access 2007.i want find mix and max function with datetime.

**This Code:**

```
SELECT inf.SSN AS EmpNo, ck.CHECKTIME AS CHKDATE,Min(ck.CHECKTIME) AS TIMEIN, Max(ck.CHECKTIME) AS TIMEOUT
FROM CHECKINOUT ck INNER JOIN USERINFO inf ON ck.Badgenumber = inf.Badgenumber
WHERE (((ck.CHECKTIME)>=#20/03/2013#)
Group By inf.SSN, ck.CHECKTIME
ORDER BY inf.SSN, ck.CHECKTIME
```

**Result:**

```
EmpNo   |     CHKDATE    |  TIMEIN             | TIMEOUT
1290005 | 20/3/2556 7:24:52  |  20/3/2556 7:24:52  | 20/3/2556 7:24:52
1290005 | 20/3/2556 19:07:54 |  20/3/2556 19:07:54 | 20/3/2556 19:07:54
1290005 | 21/3/2556 7:14:29  |  21/3/2556 7:14:29  | 21/3/2556 7:14:29
1320004 | 20/3/2556 7:28:57  |  20/3/2556 7:28:57  | 20/3/2556 7:28:57
1320004 | 20/3/2556 17:05:23 |  20/3/2556 17:05:23 | 20/3/2556 17:05:23
1320004 | 21/3/2556 7:15:30  |  21/3/2556 7:15:30  | 21/3/2556 7:15:30
```

**But I want Result:**

```
EmpNo   |     CHKDATE    |  TIMEIN             | TIMEOUT
1290005 | 20/3/2556 00:00:00 |  20/3/2556 7:24:52  | 20/3/2556 19:07:54
1290005 | 21/3/2556 00:00:00 |  21/3/2556 7:14:29  | 21/3/2556 7:14:29
1320004 | 20/3/2556 00:00:00 |  20/3/2556 7:28:57  | 20/3/2556 17:05:23
1320004 | 21/3/2556 00:00:00 |  21/3/2556 7:15:30  | 21/3/2556 7:15:30
```

How query this result in Access 2007. Thanks For your Time. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access SQL supports a `DateValue()` function which returns the date portion of a Date/Time value.  (Actually it gives you midnight for that date.)  I think it should be useful for what you want.

```sql
SELECT
    inf.SSN AS EmpNo,
    DateValue(ck.CHECKTIME) AS CHKDATE,
    Min(ck.CHECKTIME) AS TIMEIN,
    Max(ck.CHECKTIME) AS TIMEOUT
FROM
    CHECKINOUT ck
    INNER JOIN USERINFO inf
    ON ck.Badgenumber = inf.Badgenumber
WHERE ck.CHECKTIME>=#2013/03/20#
GROUP BY inf.SSN, DateValue(ck.CHECKTIME)
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to group by EmpNo and ChkDate